# JavaScriptSerializer: Serialize a list + a string into JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

I want to use JavaScriptSerializer to send a package of JSON data that contains both a list of objects as well as a string, identified like ChatLogPath.  As far as I can tell, that class can only serialize one object -- being the list -- and if I try to append multiple ones it obviously just creates invalid JSON like {...}{...} which won't work.

Is there any way to do this?  I'm insanely new to C# and ASP.NET MVC so forgive me if this is a dumb question :)

Edit: here's my code as of right now.

```
    string chatLogPath = "path_to_a_text_file.txt";
    IEnumerable<ChatMessage> q = ...
    ...
    JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return json.Serialize(q) + json.Serialize(chatLogPath);
```

Which will output the array like this in JSON { ... } followed by the chatLogPath { ... }.  In other words, it can't work since that's invalid JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to get a single JSON object with the array and path together is to create a class or dynamic object with each as a property/field of it.

Class example:

```
public class ChatInformation {
  public IEnumerable<ChatMessage> messages;
  public string chatLogPath;
}
...
var output = new ChatInformation {
  messages = ...,
  chatLogPath = "path_to_a_text_file.txt"
};
return json.Serialize(output);
```

Dynamic example (requires .NET 4+):

```
dynamic output = new ExpandoObject {
  messages = ...,
  chatLogPath = "path_to_a_text_file.txt"
};
return json.Serialize(output);
```

Anonymous Type example (if you don't care to have another class, nor are you on .NET 4):

```
var output = new {
  messages = ...,
  chatLogPath = "path_to_a_text_file.txt"
};
return json.Serialize(output);
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that, but that absolutely makes sense.  Thanks a ton!